# Reload page with hash on it

Tags: jquery, hash, reload

I have a problem with anchor and reload page.

When we open my page, we go to a anchor to skip the header and go directly in the content (because a animation start in the content and I want the user see it)

After animation stop, a button appear the replay the same animation. So I want to reload the page and go the the same anchor as when we open the page, but when we click, they go to the top of the page.

I have a page with a button to reload the page (in my case reload the page restart the animation on my page because animation start when we enter to the page)

Some of my code (simplify code)

when the page open I do that (and it's work):

```
window.location.hash = '#container';
```

the button (appear after the animation):

the HTML:

```
    <button class="bouton blanc bouton-laureats rejouer"><img src="assets/imgs/rejouer.png" />Rejouer</button>
```

the JQuery:

```
$('.page-gagnants-animation .rejouer').on('click', function(){
    window.location.hash = '#container';
    window.location.reload();
 });
```

when I click it, I go the the top of the page but I want to go directly on #container(the content). I was already here but a want to stay on #container.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

```
<a href="pagelink#hashcontent" onclick="window.location.reload()">Reload</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

> the button (appear after the animation):

Does it appear because it's dynamically added?  If so, your jquery trigger is slightly off.

```
$('.page-gagnants-animation .rejouer').on('click', function(){
```

should be

```
$('.page-gagnants-animation').on('click', " .rejouer", function(){
```

because [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) doesn't watch the entire DOM for new added elements, you have to tell it where to look.

Alternatively, if you really can't get the javascript to execute the way you expect, why not just use a good old fashioned anchor tag?

```
<button class="bouton blanc bouton-laureats rejouer">
    <a href="#container"><img src="assets/imgs/rejouer.png" />Rejouer</a>
</button>
```

As an added bonus, you won't have to worry about javascript support on any browser, as pretty much everything will support this.

---

*Edit, my original answer (below) isn't true.  You can include the # if you want to.*

*When you use window.location.hash, you don't include the #.*

```
window.location.hash = 'container';
window.location.reload();
```

*should work.*

---

Comment: Thank you! I finally found a answer myself. I juste replace the url with the same url without the anchor and because my code add the anchor when the page open it's work.